# Embed if statement inside a "a href" tag in Razor

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to embed if statement inside an "a href" tag.

Like for example

```
<a id="spnMarkButton" href="javascript:void(0);" @if(condition here) style="display:none;" else style="display:block;" onclick="MarkStore(@storeRating.StoreId);">
```

But the code above is not working.

Answer (score 5):

You're taking the wrong approach.

In the model class, add a getter like this:

```
string MarkButtonDisplay
{
    get
    {
        if(condition here)
            return "none";
        else
            return "block";
    }
}
```

And change the markup to:

```
<a id="spnMarkButton" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display: @Model.MarkButtonDisplay;" onclick="MarkStore(@storeRating.StoreId);">
```

Don't mix logic and markup.

Comment: _Don't mix logic and markup_. It's funny because this is much true as it is utopian for all patterns trying to separate interface from logic. Look at your example: you're moving CSS values from the markup to the model which is exactly the opposite of what you're saying. In my opinion this is actually one of those few cases where logic inside markup seems perfectly reasonable. My 2 cents :)

Comment: What if I'm trying to do this inside ``public async Task OnGetAsync(string id)`` and ``string id`` is part of the condition?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason it why it needs to be embedded in the tag?

```
@if(condition here)
{
    <a id="spnMarkButton" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:none;" onclick="MarkStore(@storeRating.StoreId);">
}
else
{
    <a id="spnMarkButton" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:block;" onclick="MarkStore(@storeRating.StoreId);">
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you use code blocks

```
@if (condition) {…} else {…}
```

Comment: it doesn't work...  <a id="spnMarkButton" href="javascript:void(0);" @if(condition) { style="display:none;" } />

Comment: You need to wrap your style in <text></text> tags tags ie <text>style=""</text>

Comment: Are you using @if (condition) {<text>style="display : none;"</text>} else {…  this is correct razor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="spnMarkButton" href="javascript:void(0);" @if(1==1) { <text>style="display:none;"</text> } else { <text>style="display:block;"</text> } onclick="MarkStore(@(storeRating.StoreId));">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do easy with (?:) operator, or better with helper class:

```
@* Inline with MvcHtmlString *@
<a id="spnMarkButton" href="javascript:void(0);" @(Model == null ? new MvcHtmlString("style=\"display:none;\"") : new MvcHtmlString("style=\"display:block;\""))>My link 1</a>

@* Inline with Html.Raw *@
<a id="spnMarkButton" href="javascript:void(0);" @(Model == null  ? Html.Raw("style=\"display:none;\"") : Html.Raw("style=\"display:block;\""))>My link 2</a>

@* Using helper class - cleanest *@
<a id="spnMarkButton" href="javascript:void(0);" @RenderDisplayStyle()>My link 3</a>

@helper RenderDisplayStyle(){
    if (Model == null)
    {
        @:style="display:none"
    }
    else
    {
        @:style="display:block"
    }
}
```

Helper class is cleanest way in my opinion.